# Как получить число из SQL-запроса?

Tags: java, postgresql, sql

Возникла проблема: не могу получить число из SQL-запроса. Есть запрос:

```
SELECT COUNT (*) FROM first;
```

По идее, он должен мне вернуть количество строк в таблице, которое я смогу записать в переменную. Но каким бы из методов `.exequteXXX(...);` я этот запрос не вызывал, пишет либо ошибку, либо не возвращает ничего:

```
        int c = three.statem.executeUpdate("SELECT COUNT (*) FROM first;");
```

Подскажите, каким образом мне сделать так, чтобы запрос возвращал число?

Comment: А Вы уверены, что функция возвращает тип INT? Может, требуется приведение к INT? И еще, попробуйте поставить вместо * имя одного из полей.

Comment: 1) execueUpdate - совсем не то.

2) SQL-запрос executeQuery вернет ResultSet, а не конкретное значение/значения поля/полей.

3) Почитайте, пожалуй, документацию по java.sql.Statement: execute, executeQuery.

А потом уж и про ResultSet.

Comment: @Вячеслав Кириченко, в IDE написано, что возвравщает int, приведение не помогает. Пишет "org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Результат возвращён когда его не ожидалось."

Comment: @Expo1on

Returns: either (1) the row count for SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements or (2) 0 for SQL statements that return nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Было интересно решить задачу. Пару часов и сделал. Инструменты: желание сделать и [туториал](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html).
Одно из решений:

```
public int readData() throws SQLException {

        String query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS quantity FROM Customers;";
        int quantity = -1;

        connection = getConnection();
        statement = connection.createStatement();

        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);

        if (resultSet.next()) {
            String temp = resultSet.getString("quantity"); // "quantity" - псевдоним из запроса
            quantity = Integer.parseInt(temp);

        }
        statement.close();
        connection.close();

        return quantity;
    }
```